Javascript library that can do List and Grid layout
I am trying to find JavaScript library that has functionality to change views, List and Grid, Please check below screenshots for both views.


User should be able to change view from dropdown.
I have checked DataTable and Masonry Libraries. but I couldn't find required feature in single library.
Please suggest.

Can't you just use Bootstrap?

You can achieve this behavior using the Syncfusion JavaScript Datagrid component.
Online Demo: https://ej2.syncfusion.com/demos/#/fluent2/grid/column-template.html
Syncfusion offers a free community license also. https://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense
Note: I work for Syncfusion
